# Does UseSQLServer() connection can be replaced by ODBC in asp.net Core 3.1 project?

Tags: asp.net, odbc

I have made a project in ASP.NET core 3.1, the project is connected with sql server database by using UseSQLServer()-connection string. Client requirement is to replace it with ODBC.
Is their any way to replace SQLClient with ODBC?
Thank is advance.